# Retrofit, стандартный NavigationDrawer, RuntimeException, сеттинг в header

Tags: java, android, retrofit, android-navigation-drawer

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

ApiCaller userInfo;
User myAccount;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    userInfo = Core.buildInterceptCaller();
    Call<User> call = userInfo.showAccount();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful())
                myAccount = response.body();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView nickname = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nickname);
    nickname.setText(myAccount.getNickName());
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
}
```

Вот такой код. Хочу никнейм полученного юзера запихнуть в хедер `NawDrawer`, но вылазит вот такое:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eleks.fry.imessmobile/com.eleks.fry.imessmobile.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.blahblah.blah.blahblah.models.User.getNickName()' on a null object reference

Помоите решить проблему?

Comment: Проверьте через логирование, какой никнейм вам возвращает Retrofit

Answer (score 2):

Стектрейс вам недвусмыслено говорит, что метод `getNickName()` не может быть вызван, потому что объект `User` ссылается на `null`

Answer (score 0):

Вы пытаетесь использовать `myAccount` сразу после запуска запроса, в тот момент когда он ещё не завершился т.к. вызов `call.enqueue()` является асинхронным. Соответственно метод `onResponse()` вызовется только спустя какое то время после запуска запроса.

Перенесите этот код в метод `onResponse()`

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
TextView nickname = (TextView)headerView.findViewById(R.id.txt_nickname);
nickname.setText(myAccount.getNickName());
```